# Loop through span and find the closest check box

Tags: jquery, html

I have this jquery that need to loop through each row and if the fourth column is Pending then it should disable the checkbox.

My jquery is working until the loop, i don't know why it does not enter the if statement and how do i find the closest checkbox?

**HTML can't be edited. Platform restricted.**

I tried to do it the other way around where I will loop through the checkboxes and find the closest span with 'PENDING' value but it did not work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    var zoneObject = $('.cell').find('span');
    $(zoneObject).each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text().replace(/ /g, '');
      var pending = "Pending";
      // if text is pending then check box is disabled
      if (text === pending) {
        var chx = $(this).find(':checkbox');
        $(chx).prop("disabled", true);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <button id='button'>
    Click Me
    </button>
  <table id='table1'>
    <tbody>
      <tr class='und'>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class='cell'>
                  <input type='checkbox' />

                </td>
                <td class='cell'>
                  <span>
                      one
                    </span>

                </td>
                <td class='cell'>
                  <span>
                      233232
                    </span>

                </td>
                <td class='cell'>
                  <span>
                      Pending   
                    </span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='und'>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input type='checkbox' />
                </td>
                <td class='cell'>
                  <span>
                      one
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class='cell'>
                  <span>
                      233232
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class='cell'>
                  <span>
                      s
                    </span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `$(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox')`

Comment: thanks this worked @Satpal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change following two things

1). 
`if (text === pending) //Here might be remains newline character thats why you have to use trim function to remove leading and trailing blank space`

to

`if ($.trim(text) === pending)`

2). `var chx = $(this).find(':checkbox');`

to

`var chx =$(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox');`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8o1qrhaj/)**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `replace` use `trim` to remove space before and after string.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    var zoneObject = $('.cell').find('span');
    $(zoneObject).each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text();
      text=text.trim();
      var pending = "Pending";
      // if text is pending then check box is disabled
      if (text == pending) {
        var chx = $(this).parent().parent().find(':checkbox');
        $(chx).prop("disabled", true);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <button id='button'>
    Click Me
    </button>
  <table id='table1'>
    <tbody>
      <tr class='und'>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class='cell'>
                  <input type='checkbox' />

                </td>
                <td class='cell'>
                  <span>
                      one
                    </span>

                </td>
                <td class='cell'>
                  <span>
                      233232
                    </span>

                </td>
                <td class='cell'>
                  <span>
                      Pending   
                    </span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='und'>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input type='checkbox' />
                </td>
                <td class='cell'>
                  <span>
                      one
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class='cell'>
                  <span>
                      233232
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class='cell'>
                  <span>
                      s
                    </span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```